# How to query multiple property values out of order in Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a list of product names  [shirt,shoes,pants,hat,glasses]
I'm trying to perform a query that will return the products using regular expression that's case insensitive and in any order as long as the value exists.

I'm only able to query them in order
MATCH  (product:Product) WHERE product.name =~"(?i).*shirt.*shoes.*" RETURN product

How can I query them out of order ie
MATCH (product:Product) WHERE product.name=~"(?i).*hat.*shirt.*"?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly do you want to search for with the regular expression? Are you looking for product names that contain just one of the keywords in your list? Or multiple keywords?

If you just want to find product names that contain at least one of the keywords in your list you could use the string comparison operator `CONTAINS` along with the `toLower()` function to make the comparison case insensitive:

```
WITH {products} AS products
MATCH (p:Product) WHERE any(x IN products WHERE toLower(p.name) CONTAINS toLower(x))
RETURN p
```

Where `{products}` is your array of product names: `['shirt', 'shoes', 'pants', 'hats', 'glasses']`

**Edit**

To find Product nodes that contain all keywords, use the `all()` list predicate.

For example, let's say you want to find all Product nodes where the name contains "shirt" and "shoes":

```
WITH ["shirt", "shoes"] AS keywords
MATCH (p:Product) WHERE all(x IN keywords WHERE toLower(p.name) CONTAINS toLower(x))
RETURN p
```

Comment: I would like to search for product names as multiple keywords. So if I search "shirt and shoes" we need the ability to see which suppliers sell us both shirts and shoes. I understand suppliers aren't a part of this question.