# New Error in Neo4j Versions 3., Does Anyone have any Answers?

Tags: neo4j, compiler-errors, cypher

The query below was a perfectly suitable answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38702414/how-to-query-multiple-property-values-out-of-order-in-cypher)

```
WITH ["seafood"] AS keywords
MATCH (p:Product) WHERE all(x IN keywords WHERE toLower(p.name) CONTAINS toLower(x))
RETURN p
```

But now I'm getting the following error in versions 3.0.3 and 3.0.4:

Expected a string value for , but got: [Ljava.lang.String;@3cac07cf; perhaps you'd like to cast to a string it with str().

Any direction will be very much appreciated.

Comment: and `p.name` is always a string? If you change to `toLower(str(p.name))` do you still get an error?

Comment: Yes I do:Unknown function 'str' (line 2, column 57 (offset: 89))
"MATCH (p:Product) WHERE all(x IN keywords WHERE toLower(str(p.name)) CONTAINS toLower(x))"
                                                         ^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @WilliamLyon suggests, perhaps `p.name` is not always a string. It is possible that in 3.0.3 the `CONTAINS` clause is now more strictly disallowing comparisons between values of different types.

Try this:

```
WITH ["seafood"] AS keywords
MATCH (p:Product)
WHERE ALL(x IN keywords WHERE TOLOWER(TOSTRING(p.name)) CONTAINS toLower(x))
RETURN p;
```

#### Alternate answer

This might also work for you. In 3.0.3, the `=~` regular expression operator does not seem to be bothered by non-string values. Also, the `(?i)` flag avoids the need to use `TOLOWER`. For performance, the query generates the regular expressions just once at the top, instead of in the `WHERE` clause, where it would have been done N times (where N is the number of `Product` nodes).

```
WITH ["seafood"] AS keywords
WITH REDUCE(s = [], x IN keywords | s + ('(?i).*' + x + '.*')) AS regexps
MATCH (p:Product)
WHERE all(x IN regexps WHERE p.name =~ x)
RETURN p
```

Comment: CyberSam your first answer returns the following error:Expected a String, Number or Boolean, got: [Ljava.lang.String;@4cade484

Comment: Can you show a `name` value that is causing the error?

Comment: Your alternate answer actually did fix the issue. I just needed to add the "?" to the (i) case-insensitive syntax, and it's working like a charm. Is it possible for you to explain why?

Comment: That was a typo. I have fixed my answer.